# Camera's in Linux switch filename on boot

Tags: linux, video, v4l2, zoneminder

I've got a few camera's for use in Zoneminder. But they tend to switch places upon boot.
One tiem camera a will get /dev/video0, the other time it will be /dev/video1.

Is there a way to set these filenames, to make them permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, with the help of **udev** rules. See **/etc/udev/rules.d** (in Debian based distros).

Basically, you can bind the device to a name using vendor and other information available on the device via USB interface. `$ lsusb` and `$ usb-devices` help you determining the correct information about your devices. And udev documentation helps with the actual rule syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a small number of known cameras, the best approach for writing a `udev` rule is probably to use the serial numbers to distinguish them (as this will work even if they are the same model).

I have found [this reference](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) really good for getting started with `udev`.